# EuropeCV: Error "\ecvtitle undefined"

Tags: templates, sharelatex, cv, europecv

I am building a resume in sharelatex, i am getting a warning message, i wonder there may be some problem. I am using the German language setting as language as "resume language". EuropeCV (https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/europecv) (<- Link), image as below, how to rectify this? 
below code is a tex file code. class file code is same as in the link given i.e in the given project.

```
\documentclass[helvetica,openbib,nologo,notitle,totpages]{europecv}%removed notitle, flagCMYK, replaced logo with nologo
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.27cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage[german]{babel}
 \usepackage{url}
 \usepackage{setspace} %package to control the overall spacing



 \makeatletter%
 \renewcommand*\ecvtitle{%taken from definition file ecven.def and adapted to requirement 
\ecv@utf{\Large\textbf{L\ecv@kern e\ecv@kern b\ecv@kern e\ecv@kern
            n\ecv@kern s\ecv@kern l\ecv@kern a\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern   f\ecv@kern }}
}
\def\ecv@picture[#1]#2{%
\def\ecvarg{#2}%
\ifx\@empty\ecvarg\renewcommand*{\ecvdrawpicture}{}\else%
\renewcommand*{\ecvdrawpicture}{\begin{picture}(120,0)(0,90)\includegraphics[#1]{#2}\end{picture}}%adjust the (0,50) params to fine tune the picture position
\fi}%    
\makeatother%
\setstretch{0.9}% sets the line spacing to 90%



\ecvname{Doe, Joe}
\ecvfootername{Joe Doe}
\ecvaddress{Nowhere in London, England, UK}
\ecvtelephone{12345678}
\ecvfax{12345678}
\ecvemail{\url{email@address.com}}
\ecvnationality{English}
\ecvdateofbirth{Dec 24 1990}
\ecvgender{male}
\ecvpicture[width=2cm]{lion.png}
\ecvbeforepicture{\ecvspace{0cm}\raggedleft}%reduces the space before the  picture => "Personal info" goes up; \raggedleft keeps the picture to the right side
%\ecvfootnote{For more information call me}
%\ecvfootnote{For more information call me}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}


\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[5pt]

\ecvsection{Work experience}

\ecvitem{Date}{2010 -- 2013}
\ecvitem{Occupation or position held}{CV writer, Very Big Company}

\ecvsection{Education and training}

\ecvitem{Place and Date}{Very Big University, 2008 -- 2010}
\ecvitem[10pt]{Title of qualification awarded}{MSc in Nothinglogy}

\ecvitem{Place and Date}{Big University, 2005 -- 2008}
\ecvitem{Title of qualification awarded}{BSc in Nothinglogy}


\ecvsection{Personal skills and~competences}

\ecvmothertongue[5pt]{English}
\ecvitem{\large Other language(s)}{French, German}
\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage{French}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}
\ecvlanguage{German}{good}{good}{good}{good}{good}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]{(*)}

\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Social skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Organisational skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Technical skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Computer skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Artistic skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\large Other skills and competences}{Replace this text by a description of these competences and indicate where they were acquired (remove if not relevant).}
\ecvitem{\large Driving licence(s)}{State here whether you hold a driving licence and if so for which categories of vehicle. (Remove if not relevant).}

\ecvsection{Additional information}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Include here any other information that may be relevant, for example contact persons, references, etc. (Remove heading if not relevant).}

\ecvitem{}{\textbf{Personal interests}}
\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Musics, Movies, Golf}

\ecvitem{}{\textbf{References}}
\ecvitem{}{Person One, Person Two}

\end{europecv}


\end{document}      


 and the class file is the same as given in the link (and template given) .   and .def files (evcde.def )i have changed i will attach the code here. 

%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%
% Translation completed on 2005/04/08
\ProvidesFile{ecvde.def}[europecv German definitions]
% Personal information
\def\ecv@infosectionkey{\ecv@utf{Angaben zur Person}}
\def\ecv@namekey{\ecv@utf{Nachname / Vorname}}
\def\ecv@addresskey{\ecv@utf{Adresse}}
\def\ecv@telkey{\ecv@utf{Telefon}}
\def\ecv@mobilekey{\ecv@utf{Mobil}}
\def\ecv@faxkey{\ecv@utf{Fax}}
\def\ecv@emailkey{\ecv@utf{E-mail}}
\def\ecv@nationalitykey{\ecv@utf{Staatsangeh\"origkeit}}
\def\ecv@birthkey{\ecv@utf{Geburtsdatum}}
\def\ecv@genderkey{\ecv@utf{Geschlecht}}
 % Footer
\def\ecv@pagekey{\ecv@utf{Seite}}
\def\ecv@cvofkey{\ecv@utf{Lebenslauf von}}
 % Language table
 \def\ecv@mothertonguekey{\ecv@utf{Muttersprache}}
 \def\ecv@assesskey{\ecv@utf{Selbstbeurteilung}}
 \def\ecv@levelkey{\ecv@utf{Nivieau}}
 \def\ecv@understandkey{\ecv@utf{Verstehen}}
  \def\ecv@speakkey{\ecv@utf{Sprechen}}
  \def\ecv@writekey{\ecv@utf{Schreiben}}
 \def\ecv@listenkey{\ecv@utf{H\"oren}}
 \def\ecv@readkey{\ecv@utf{Lesen}}
 \def\ecv@interactkey{\ecv@utf{An Gespr\"achen teilnehmen}}
 \def\ecv@productkey{\ecv@utf{Zusammen\-h\"angendes Sprechen}}
 \def\ecv@langfooterkey{\ecv@utf{Nivieau: A1 und A2: Elementar-B1 und B2    Selbst\"andig- C1 und C2: Kompetent}}
 \def\ecv@cefbasickey{\ecv@utf{Elementare Sprachverwendung}}
 \def\ecv@cefindepkey{\ecv@utf{Selbst\"andige Sprachverwendung}}
 \def\ecv@cefprofkey{\ecv@utf{Kompetente Sprachverwendung}}

 \renewcommand*\ecvtitle{\ecv@utf{\Large\textbf{E\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern
 r\ecv@kern o\ecv@kern p\ecv@kern a\ecv@kern s\ecv@kern s}\\[5pt]
 \Large\textbf{L\ecv@kern e\ecv@kern b\ecv@kern e\ecv@kern
 n\ecv@kern s\ecv@kern l\ecv@kern a\ecv@kern u\ecv@kern f\ecv@kern}}}
```

[image]

Comment: That is not a warning, that is an error. You are using `notitle` anyway.

Comment: The template as linked does not show the error depicted in your image. Please show us a compilable minimal example. Copy the code directly, do not use a screenshot.

Comment: Just search the internet. Then you will find https://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013 There you can download it.  On this page are several questions for europass.  Just use the page search with "europass" with 21 results: http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=europass

Comment: Copy the english example from the zip file, change the three occurencies of `english` to `german` in the preamble and compile three times.  Of course you have to add german informations instead the english ones ...  If that does not help, please ask a new question please!

Comment: @prasadak.kle In general, you are not allowed to change `cls` files.

Answer (score 2):

An example of a german cv shows the following MWE, based on the current class version of europass. You can find it on http://github.com/leinardi/europecv2013 , please download it and try the following german MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
  helvetica,
  german,   % <=========================================================
  logo,
  notitle,
  totpages,
  utf8
]{europecv2013}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.2cm,left=1.2cm,right=1.2cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[german]{babel} % <==========================================
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}

\ecvname{Vor- und Nachname(n) hier angeben}
\ecvaddress{Straße, Hausnummer, PLZ, Ort (Staat) hier angeben}
\ecvtelephone[Telefon hier angeben]{Mobilnummer hier angeben}
\ecvemail{E-Mail-Adresse hier angeben}
\ecvhomepage{\href{Homepage URL}{Persönliche Website hier angeben (ohne ``http://'')}}
\ecvlinkedin{\href{LinkedIn public profile URL}{öffentliche LinkedIn-Profile-URL ohne ``http://''}}
\ecvgender{Geschlecht hier angeben}
\ecvdateofbirth{tt/mm/jjjj}
\ecvnationality{Nationalität/-en hier angeben}

\ecvfootnote{© European Union, 2002-2015 | http://europass.cedefop.europa.eu}
%\ecvbeforepicture{\raggedleft}
%\ecvpicture[width=2.5cm]{file-immagine-eps}
%\ecvafterpicture{\ecvspace{-37mm}}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{german}  % <============================================

\begin{europecv}
\ecvpersonalinfo[10pt]

\ecvposition{Angestrebte Tätigkeit}{Aus der Liste wählen: Angestrebte Stelle / Beruf / Angestrebte Tätigkeit /Angestrebtes Studium / Selbsteinschätzung (Löschen Sie die nicht relevanten Rubriken in der linken Spalte)}

\ecvsection{Berufserfahrung}%{Work experience}
%[Add separate entries for each experience. Start from the most recent.]

\ecvworkexperience{Daten einfügen (von--bis)}{Aktuelle Stelle / Position angeben}{Arbeitgeber eingeben}{Arbeitsort hier angeben (falls relevant, vollständige Adresse, Webseite)}{Wichtigsten Tätigkeiten und Zuständigkeiten hier angeben}

\ecvsection{Schul- und Berufsbildung}%Education and training}
%[Add separate entries for each course. Start from the most recent.]

\ecveducation{Daten einfügen (von--bis)}{Erworbene / zu erwerbende Qualifikation angeben}{Name und Ort der Bildungseinrichtung ergänzen (falls relevant auch das Land)}{Hauptfächer und beruflichen Fähigkeiten hier angeben, die im Rahmen des betreffenden Bildungs-
bzw. Ausbildungsgangs vermittelt wurden.}{EQR-Einstufung (oder andere) angeben, falls bekannt und relevant.}

\ecvsection{Persönliche Fähigkeiten}%{Personal skills}

\ecvmothertongue[20pt]{Muttersprache(n) hier angeben}
\ecvlanguageheader
\ecvlastlanguage{Sprache hier angeben}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvBTwo}{\ecvBOne}{\ecvATwo}
\ecvlanguagefooter[10pt]

\ecvitem[5pt]{Bezeichnung des Zertifikats und europäisches Niveau, falls bekannt.}{}
\ecvitem[10pt]{\textbf{English}}{Blafasel, Total score: 333, date: 2015-10-21}


%             {Communication skills}
\ecvitem[10pt]{Kommunikative Fähigkeiten}{Kommunikative Fähigkeiten hier angeben. Beschreiben Sie, in welchem Zusammenhang sie erworben wurden. Beispiel:\par
Gute kommunikative Fähigkeiten, die ich durch meine Erfahrung als Verkaufsleiter erworben habe}
\ecvitem[10pt]{Organisations- und Führungstalent}{Organisations- und Führungstalent hier angeben. Beschreiben Sie, in welchem Zusammenhang sie erworben wurden Beispiel:\par
Führungskompetenz (aktuell verantwortlich für ein Team von 10 Personen)}
\ecvitem[10pt]{Berufliche Fähigkeiten}{Berufliche Fähigkeiten, die Sie sonst noch in keiner Rubrik angeführt haben, hier angeben.
Beschreiben Sie, in welchem Zusammenhang sie erworben wurden. Beispiel:\par
Gute Kenntnisse der Prozesse der Qualitätskontrolle (momentan bin ich verantwortlich für das
Qualitäts-Audit.) }
\ecvitem[10pt]{Digitale Kompetenz}{digitale Kompetenzen hier angeben. Beschreiben Sie, in welchem Zusammenhang sie erworben wurden. Beispiel:\par
Gute Kenntnisse von dem Office-Paket (Textverarbeitung, Tabellenkalkulation und
Präsentationssoftware)}
\ecvitem[10pt]{Sonstige Fähigkeiten}{Sonstige relevante Fähigkeiten hier angeben. Erläutern Sie, in welchem Zusammenhang Sie diese Fähigkeiten erworben haben. Beispiel:\par
Erste Hilfe: Ich bin im Rahmen meiner Tauchausbildung als Ersthelferin zertifiziert.}

%        Driving licence
\ecvitem{Führerschein}{Klasse Ihres Führerscheins hier angeben. Beispiel:\par
B}

\ecvsection{Zusätzliche Informationen}%{Additional information}

\ecvitem[10pt]{Publikationen, Präsentationen, Projekte, Konferenzen, Seminare, Auszeichnungen und Preise, Mitgliedschaften, Referenzen und Quellenagaben hier angeben}{Entfernen Sie nicht relevante Überschriften in der linken Spalte.}

\ecvsection{Anlagen}

\ecvitem[10pt]{}{Auflistung aller Dokumente, die dem Lebenslauf beiliegen (Kopien von Abschlusszeugnissen und Qualifikationen, Arbeitszeugnisse, Publikationen etc.) hier angeben. Beispiele:
\begin{itemize}
\item Kopie des Abschlusszeugnisses als Ingenieurin 
\item Europass Sprachenpass
\item Arbeitszeugnis (Anderson and Dobbs)
\end{itemize}}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

with the first resulting pdf page:

[image: first resulting page]